# remove block of text from config file using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to remove the below section from samba config file smb.conf.

```
[public]
  path = /opt/samba/public
  guest ok = yes
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  read only = no
```

Blockinfile module won't work as there are no markers . Lineinfile will also have a problem as there are lines which are common to other sections. e.g

```
 browsable = yes
 writable = yes
```

How do I remove these lines using ansible?

PS: replacing the config file with a new one is not possible as each server has a unique user mapped to it (not ideal when running batch jobs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/smb.conf
    regexp: '^\[public\][^[]+'
    replace: ''
    backup: yes
```

This should remove everything between `[public]` and `[` or `EOF`.

Comment: Updated link: [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html)

Comment: Another way to match across multiple lines is `[\s\S]*`: `end of first line to remove[\s\S]*start of last line to remove` : the way `replace` uses regexes means that the wildcard character `.` doesn't match newlines.

Answer (score 7):

Ansible has native [ini-file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html) support, which is a much cleaner way to accomplish this.

```yaml
- name: remove public block
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/smb.conf
    section: public
    state: absent
```

Comment: This is preferred and safer

Comment: @RayOei But it only helps for the example, not the question in the title...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Not sure what you mean here? This support is meant to (from the doc): `Manage (add, remove, change) individual settings in an INI-style file without having to manage the file as a whole`. So this will work for any type of config file where you want to manipulate on a line per line basis..

Comment: @RayOei I mean a question about removing a block of text from e.g. a haproxy config file would be marked as a duplicate of this, but this answer does not answer "how to remove a block of text from a file" it answers "how do I remove a section from an INI file"

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that will remove the entire  tag in an apache config file:

```
replace:
path: "{{my_path}}"
regexp: '^<Directory /var/www/>(.*\n)*</Directory>$'
replace: ''
```