# Remove Exact Block of lines in config file with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to delete a block of text with ansible from a config file.

```
- name: Remove Block Of Text
   blockinfile:
     path: /oracle/config/domains/soa_domain/config/config.xml
     block: |
      <file-store>
        <name/>
        <directory/>
        <target>AdminServer</target>
      </file-store>
     state: absent
```

Nothing happens. Hope someone has an answer.

Kind Regards

M

Comment: ```blockinfile``` relies on commented markup to determine which text is managed by ansible and which text isn't. You will need to surround your text with a BEGIN and END marker. Take a look at the marker field on [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html). The default is ```# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK``` and ```# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK```

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your reply. Yes i saw that. But i need to remove this exact text. So i much switch to a shell command to remove the lines? Or is there another possibility within ansible?

Comment: You might try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045043/remove-block-of-text-from-config-file-using-ansible) using the replace command. You also could try using lineinfile and looping over the lines if they are unique to the file. If your file is always an XML you might try using the [xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html) module to load your file in and remove that particular segment from the data itself and recreate the file from the new data.

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: Remove Block Of Text
   blockinfile:
     path: /oracle/config/domains/soa_domain/config/config.xml
     marker: ''#{mark} same content you have given while creating block''
     block: |
      <file-store>
        <name/>
        <directory/>
        <target>AdminServer</target>
      </file-store>
     state: absent
```

note: marker is most important parameter in blockinfile module to add or remove a block. Actually marker_begin and marker_end ( {mark} option in marker )are the markers blockinfile considers to delete any block you want to delete. So, whatever block you want to delete just put #begin and #end before and after the block similar to what ansible uses to put when it creates a block inside a file using blockinfile module.

For example:
I created block with blockinfile module like this

```
config:
#BEGIN for template file
- mname: GMLC_NLT
  template: T1
  action: add
  script: change-config.sh
  tte: START/CONFIG/BINARY/LIBRARY/EXECUTE/ANYSCRIPT
#END for template file
- mname: GMLC_NLT
  template: T1
  action: add
  state: RUNNING/STOP
  file_name: ConfigParamSheet.xlsx
  sheet_name: config_sheet
  p_details:
  - p_name: log level
    p_value: INFO
    CLI_Name: loglevel
    EMS_Name: logLevel
```

where tasks will look like
- name: modify config in template file
blockinfile:
dest: template.yaml
backup: yes
insertafter: "config:"
marker: "#{mark} for template file"
content: |
- mname: GMLC_NLT
template: T1
action: add
script: change-config.sh
tte: START/CONFIG/BINARY/LIBRARY/EXECUTE/ANYSCRIPT

Now when you have to delete this block, you have to use this task

```
  - name: modify config in template file
    blockinfile:
     state: absent
     path: template.yaml
     marker: "#{mark} for template file"
     content: |
       - mname: GMLC_NLT
         template: T1
         action: add
         script: change-config.sh
         tte: START/CONFIG/BINARY/LIBRARY/EXECUTE/ANYSCRIPT
```

So what ansible does, it searches #BEGIN for template file and #END for template file in the template.yaml file given in path and removes content with the marker too.